# The Elimination Method

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I know how to use the elimination method - just that I can't quite figure it out on these type of linear systems: 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
y &=& –\frac{5}{3}x + 3 \\
y &=& \frac{1}{3}x - 3
\end{array}
$$

They do line up perfectly, so does this mean it becomes:
$
0 = \dfrac{-4x}{3}
$??

Comment: Look again. It would be $0 = 2x - 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you added the equations since the 3's cancelled. Then left side is $2y$ not $0.$ Try subtracting instead.

Comment: Oh shoot; thanks :)